# event start-end into hot encoding in python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, one-hot-encoding

I have a pandas dataframe with 2 columns "type" and "sign" as follows

```
    type    sign
0   open    A
1   open    B
2   open    D
3   close   B
4   close   D
5   open    B
6   close   B
7   close   A
```

"A" + "open" means that event A has started happening. "A" + "close" means that event A has stopped. 
I need to vectorize it, when time is a major issue (the list is actually about 40 million lines long).
Kind of like one-hot-encoding, but i need "1" to exist if and only if an event is "active". 
for example, for this case the results should be:

```
    A   B   C   D   type    sign
0   1   0   0   0   open    A
1   1   1   0   0   open    B
2   1   1   0   1   open    D
3   1   0   0   1   close   B
4   1   0   0   0   close   D
5   1   1   0   0   open    B
6   1   0   0   0   close   B
7   0   0   0   0   close   A
```

Ideas? 
thanks

Comment: why does index 6 has a 1 for sign B?

Comment: it should't. edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your data, you can just do a `for` loop:

```
for sign in 'ABCD':
    df[sign] = (df['type'].where(df['sign'].eq(sign))
                 .ffill()
                 .eq('open')
                 .astype(int)
               )
```

Output:

```
    type sign  A  B  C  D
0   open    A  1  0  0  0
1   open    B  1  1  0  0
2   open    D  1  1  0  1
3  close    B  1  0  0  1
4  close    D  1  0  0  0
5   open    B  1  1  0  0
6  close    B  1  0  0  0
7  close    A  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: 22 seconds for 10 millions lines. good timing! can you think of a way to increase speed? i tried multiprocess on it, but just transfering the lines to other process cause it to become unusefull

Answer (score 5):

IIUC let do `get_dummies` then do `cumsum`

```
s=df.sign.str.get_dummies().reindex(columns=list('ABCD'),fill_value=0).\
    mul(df.type.map({'open':1,'close':-1}),axis=0).cumsum()
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  1  1  0  0
2  1  1  0  1
3  1  0  0  1
4  1  0  0  0
5  1  1  0  0
6  1  0  0  0
7  0  0  0  0
df=df.join(s)
```

Comment: Brilliant idea with the mapping here :)

Comment: It doesn't scale up. when i run it on 10 million lines it doesn't complete after 5 minutes.